# "No Response" With PHP and Canon devices

Tags: php, snmp

I'm developing a little monitoring PHP interface. I'm using a lot SNMP for Windows Server and Synologys and it's working well. But with Canon printers, I have always "No response from [IP]". It's working with all brands but not with Canon.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
$snmp = new \Snmp(1, "192.168.2.173", "public",1000000,2); 
$toners['black'] = $snmp->get('.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9.1.1'); 
var_dump($snmp->getError()); 
var_dump($toners);
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: we probably can help - if we get any code to work on.

Comment: $snmp  = new \Snmp(1, "192.168.2.173", "public",1000000,2);

$toners['black']  = $snmp->get('.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9.1.1');
var_dump($snmp->getError());
var_dump($toners);

Comment: Not to ask a stupid question, but do your Canon printers actually have an SNMP interface?

Comment: Of course! I have forgotten to say, first, I tried with snmp Tester and it's work. But not with PHP...
Edit: After somes tries, it seems to work with snmp non object on PHP...